# samsung galaxy S6 Sim Network unlock pin

Tags: sim-unlocking

I Have bought a Samsung galaxy s6 model from Saudi Arabia and inserted saudi STC sim and i just made a call and brought it to India.I tried with inserting Indian SIM and it asked me for the "Sim Network Unlock Pin". My few friends say saudi sim should be used minimum 5 minutes of call but i did only 1 min. I also Have a Saudi Arabian Sim which is currently in roaming. Can I insert that particular SIM and make calls from India and get it removed. Kindly help everyone . Please...